# Twitter Bootstrap themed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I happened to use bootstrap:themed on one of my models that I generated without using scaffolding and it worked. However, I need to find the CSS Classes used for this, where in my project can i find them?

Answer (score 1):

The usual place for all the .css files in Rails 3 is app/assets/stylesheets (file with a name bootstrap.css or similar). It depends what implementation of bootstrap you are using - source files or gem . In case of gem implementation you should look for the source code (classes in your case) in the GitHub repository .